# How to kill MS SQL 2016 tcp listener

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

Got a MS 2016 cluster AG running a default instance and a named instance.  Want the named instance to run on 1434.  Killed SQL browser but SQL still listening on 1434.  How do I kill this?  **Note - don't want to take the 1433 instance offline**.

[image: SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tcp_listener_states]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Whatever it is, the solution doesn't involve *breaking* named instances - UDP 1434 is the port used by SQL Server Browser, the service that handles named instances.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem X and assume Y is the solution. When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not the original problem X. The question as is is out-of-topic anyway - it's about database administration, not programming. The *actual* problem though may be more relevant. It could be a simple misunderstanding of how SQL Server works, what named instances are or it could be a question about firewalls or port forwarding.

Comment: Your question is better suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).

Comment: I want to use tcp 1434 for my named instance but the port is taken.  I've done this previously on a standalone box with no issues.  I assumed browser service would take another port when my named instance had 1434.  Notice, on the screenshot that it isn't UDP, its TCP (i.e.  browser service is stopped).  Expected 1434 to be available but SQL still consuming it for some reason - does anyone know the reason?  Restarting default instance may clear it down but I can't restart it atm.

Answer (score 0):

TCP port 1434 is used for the Dedicated Administrator Connection (not for the SQL Server Browser, which uses UDP port 1434). To disable DAC, you can use `sp_configure` with the `'remote admin connections'` option.